# OpenVPN through proxy, can't get client ip address

Tags: proxy, openvpn

I have 3 pc's:

- pc1 hosts the VPN server
- pc2 hosts a proxy server and acts as client 1
- pc3 acts as client 2
- pc3 shares a network with pc2, but not with pc1
- pc2 shares a network with pc1.
- client1 is connected through the proxy on pc2
- client2 is also connected through the proxy on pc2

So the setup looks like this:

```
----------------
|      pc3     |
|  VPN Client2 |
|  10.100.0.3  |
----------------
       |
       | Network A
       |
----------------
|      pc2     |
| Proxy server/|
|  VPN Client1 |
|  10.100.0.2  |
----------------
       |
       | Network B
       |
----------------
|      pc1     |
|  VPN Server  |
|  10.100.0.1  |
----------------
```

Now, pc1 hosts a webserver which will get the ip address of the client making the request for the webpage.

When I make the request from PC2 I can correctly see the request came from PC2.

But when I make the request from PC3 I expected to see the VPN assigned ip address of 10.100.0.3, but instead I get the ip address from PC2 in the case when client 1 is connected, if client 1 is not connected will get the ip address of the VPN server itself (10.100.0.1)

I thought I created a direct 'tunnel' which would make pc1 think the request came directly from pc3, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You ate using a different crrt/username for each computer right?

Comment: @Zoredache No, but the server is configured to accept the same certificate multiple times

Comment: Please add your OpenVPN server and client configurations to the question, and routing tables on all nodes.

Comment: Some questions:
* Is there any proxy related envrioment var in PC3?
* PC2 is a transparent proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I am bit unclear about your expectations.

If PC2 is a proxy, and all clients are configured to use the proxy, then what you describe is what I would expect: client1 makes a request via the proxy on PC2, which in turn forwards that request to PC1.

So from a network standpoint, the request PC1 sees would indeed be coming from PC2.

If you wanted to make the IP of PC3 visible to PC1, then I suspect your best bet would be to configure your proxy to send X-Forwarded-For headers on to PC1.

I think though there may be two problems:

> But when I make the request from PC3 I expected to see the VPN assigned ip address of 10.100.0.3, but instead I get the ip address from PC2 in the case when client 1 is connected, if client 1 is not connected will get the ip address of the VPN server itself (10.100.0.1)

Does PC1 have a rule to masquerade traffic coming from the VPN? If so, then I would wonder what the IP client1 is trying to connect would be (if your client is connecting to something other than 10.100.0.1, AND you were masquerading, I would tend to think your situation is normal).

> I thought I created a direct 'tunnel' which would make pc1 think the request came directly from pc3, what am I doing wrong?

It sounds like you did, but if your clients are using a proxy for HTTP/S requests, then the direct tunnel is not going to make the VPN IP of PC3 visible, because PC3 is not directly connecting to PC1.

Could you maybe confirm whether or not you do have masquerading in place? You can do that with `sudo iptables -t nat -vnL`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I got it working in the meantime, not sure why yet, anyway the bounty is yours since it's about to expire :)